# ./path of file to execute not executing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, path

I am trying to execute  matlab from desktop path of file is

```
      /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/matlab
```

executing      `./usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/matlab`

also tried     `.//usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/matlab`

and      `./ /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/matlab`
          how it works?

Comment: just run `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/matlab` to access the binary via the full path otherwise you will run try to run it via the relative path:
`<CURRENT DIR>/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/matlab` if you put a `.` before. You can also change the add `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/` to your path variable in order to be able to execute the command `matlab` without having to speficy its whole path each time. Also change your `~/.bashrc` file and add `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin` to be able to keep those change after a reboot and just run `matlab`

Comment: Thanx a lot Allan

Comment: Did it solve your issue?

Comment: yes thanx i am trying to creating an icon using it i have to specify comand Exec=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/matlab` to access the binary via the full path otherwise you will run try to run it via the relative path: `<CURRENT DIR>/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/matlab` if you put a `.` before.

You can also change the add `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin/` to your path variable in order to be able to execute the command `matlab` without having to specify its whole path each time.

Also change your `~/.bashrc` file and add `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/bin` to be able to keep those change after a reboot and just run `matlab`